# How to find a symfony 2 field in Behat/Mink

Tags: symfony, behat, mink

I have the following input field generated by symfony:

```
<input type="text" id="my_project_localebundle_citytype_name" 
name="my_project_localebundle_citytype[name]" required="required" 
maxlength="45" class="text">
```

And I am writing my scenario like this:

```
  @javascript
  Scenario: Add a city
    Given I follow "Locales"
    And I follow "Add city"
    Then I fill in "name" with "Testing 1 2 3"
    ...
```

However the field can't be found

```
 Form field with id|name|label|value "name" not found.
```

I know I could put my complete id or name but It's too long and I want to keep it, Is there any way easier to fill it in my scenario without editing my input?

Comment: Your field doesn't have label ?

Comment: @Shady No I dont have, I just have a h3 title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood with gherkin is, it shows what's wrong with our design and UX. 
And if we can't tell the program what field fill, how a human could he?

Also the main purpose of your scenario is not to fill the form but add a city. So you should change `Then` by `And` on the line `Then I fill in "name" with "Testing 1 2 3"`.

On the other side, you can simply add a specific validation method and keep a readable feature, something like :

```
And I fill the city's creation form field with "Testing 1 2 3"
```

Then in your context :

```
/**
 * @Given /^I fill the city's creation form field with "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function fillCitysCreationForm($arg1)
{
    $this->fillField('my_project_localebundle_citytype_name', $arg1);
}
```

*PS: I didn't test the previous code, you may have to improve it.*